# Sorting answers by votes could be improved

Tags: feature-request

When I sort answers by votes and two answers have equal number of votes then their positions on list are  not deterministic. When I refresh page the answers may swap their positions.

I think that this is a bug. Refreshing page shouldn't change the order (assuming no one voted in the meantime).
Maybe answers with the same number of votes should be additionally ordered by creation time?

My intention isn't favouring or disfavouring someone for fast answering. This additional sorting criterium could be for example length of the answer.

Comment: Could someone explain why I received so many downvotes? I am new in this site.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about it - on meta voting is often used to express agreement/disagreement with a suggestion, rather than indicating a good or bad question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### That's not a bug, it's a feature!

That was made on purpose to avoid favouring one answer over the other by their position.

Comment: This is a strange feature to me and unintuitive. I am used to situation when resorting with the same criteria doesn't change the list order.

Comment: Fixed that typo for ya. (Now don't go telling me that wasn't a typo, but a feature ;-) )

Comment: @rtruszk: So, do you think it's more fair for the same answer to show up first, all the time?

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes. It's more fair. User which answered earlier could have this little advantage. But if second answer is better it can quickly go up the list.

Comment: @rtruszk: We shouldn't encourage fast answers. We should encourage _good_ answers. That's why "earlier" answers don't necessarily get shown on top.

Comment: @Cerbrus So maybe answers with the same number of votes should be sorted from the freshest to the oldest. Older answer had more time to gain votes so this could be fair to position it lower.

Comment: Newer answers aren't necessarily better. The time an answer was posted says very little about the quality of the content.

Comment: @Cerberus If time is not important so why there is sorting by oldest? Isn't existence of this option encourage fast answers more than my proposal?

Comment: @rtruszk Personally, I only find the "Oldest" tab useful when I've seen the question before and I only want to look at the newer answers to see if there's anything that hasn't really been said before. At that, I really only use it on Meta questions that receive a lot of answers...